# Pandas - Want to plot the top 20 Prices (float) for Sire (string)

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm new to Pandas so any help is much appreciated. I would like to show the top 20 performing Sires (string) by Price (float).

I am currently using

```
df.nlargest(n=20, columns=['Price'])
```

which gives me a list of the top 20 prices. I now want to plot this.

I currently have

```
df.groupby('Sire').sum().plot(y='Price', kind='bar')
```

but this gives me a list of all Sires rather than the top 20 by price.

any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: without knowing what the structure of your dataframe looks like it is hard to help. you migth just try doing both operations. Perhaps something like:

`df.groupby('Sire').sum().nlargest(n=20, columns=['Price']).plot(y='Price', kind='bar')`

or

`df.nlargest(n=20, columns=['Price']).groupby('Sire').sum().plot(y='Price', kind='bar')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what the structure of your DataFrame looks like it is hard to help. You might just try doing both operations. Perhaps something like:

```py
df.groupby('Sire').sum().nlargest(n=20, columns=['Price']).plot(y='Price', kind='bar')
```

or

```py
df.nlargest(n=20, columns=['Price']).groupby('Sire').sum().plot(y='Price', kind='bar')
```